# What is the proper syntax to map a List<T> in AutoMapper 4.1.0?

Tags: c#, automapper, data-transfer-objects

I've tried:

```
List<Employer> employers = _context.Employers.ToList();
var employersDtos = Mapper.Map<List<Employer>,List<EmployerDto>>(employers);
```

And I've also tried this:

```
var employers = _context.Employers.ToList();
var employersDtos = Mapper.Map<Employer, EmployerDto>(employers);
```

Option #1 builds but ends up with employersDtos simply being null.

Option #2 doesn't even build because we're trying to cast a List to something that isn't a list.

My mapping profile has these entries with regard to this situation:

```
            Mapper.CreateMap<Employer, EmployerDto>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<EmployerDto, Employer>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<List<Employer>, List<EmployerDto>>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<List<EmployerDto>, List<Employer>>();
```

**Keep in mind, I'm using AutoMapper 4.1.0 .** Thank you.

Comment: 'Mapper.Map<List<EmployerDto>>(employers)'

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to NOT place `Mapper.CreateMap<List<Employer>,List<EmployerDto>>()` and vice versa into the Mapping Profile. The Mapping Profile should *only* have regular maps for the non-list object types: `Mapper.CreateMap<Employer, EmployerDto>` and `Mapper.CreateMap<EmployerDto, Employer>` .

Then, `Mapper.Map<List<Employer>, List<EmployerDto>>()` may be used without incident. The key is, do not use Mapper.CreateMap for the List types.